# Font that produces the long vowel sign (ː) in LaTeX (without TIPA)

Tags: fonts

I'm currently using the kotex package, which produces all IPA symbols correctly, except for the long vowel sign `ː`.

The following code (in XeLaTeX) produces only `a` and not `aː`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kotex}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmainhangulfont{Noto Serif CJK KR}


\begin{document}

aː

\end{document}
```

Is it a font problem? What font can I use to produce `ː` without using TIPA?

Comment: It is in DejaVu Serif, DejaVu Sans, Noto Serif, Noto Sans, CMU Bright, CMU Concrete, CMU Sans Serif, CMU Serif, Baekmuk Gulim, Charis SIL, FreeMono, Fira Sans, and others.

Comment: Actually, it is in Libertinus Serif, as well.

Comment: The hangul font command does a lot of changes; you can persuade it to use a non-ko font, for mono, for example: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{kotex}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmainhangulfont{Noto Serif CJK KR}
\setmonohangulfont{Libertinus Serif}[Colour=red]
\newcommand\longv{{\ttfamily ː}}
\begin{document}
a\longv bc e\longv
\end{document}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have Noto Serif CJK KR. Here's what happens after changing that font into GungSeo (a font with Hangul characters I have on my system:

1. if I comment the `\setmainhangulfont` line, the character U+02D0 MODIFIER LETTER TRIANGULAR COLON is printed using Libertinus Serif;
2. if I uncomment the line, the character is printed using GungSeo.

Thus the conjecture is that Noto Serif CJK KR doesn't have a glyph corresponding to U+02D0.

The file `xetexko-space.sty` has indeed

```
\XeTeXcharclass "02D0 = \XKcjksymbol % ː
```

and this is what makes the character to be drawn from the Hangul font, rather than the Latin one.

If you want to keep the character to be drawn from the Latin font, change that character class assignment.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kotex}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmainhangulfont{GungSeo}

\XeTeXcharclass "02D0 = \XKlatinchar % ː

\begin{document}

aː

\end{document}
```

#### Output with the modification

[image]

#### Output without the modification

[image]

You clearly see that the glyph for the triangular colon is taken from a different font (in this case GungSeo).